# ORMLite is not creating the foreign reference

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to persist two kind of objects. Family and Subfamily. One Family has one or more Subfamilies.

The problem that I have is that I can storage data, BUT foreign reference is always NULL.

These are the classes, which create the correct database structure:

Family.java

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Family {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private ForeignCollection<Subfamily> subfamilies;

    public Family() {}

    // public getters and setters
}
```

Subfamily.java

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Subfamily {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Family family;

    @DatabaseField
    private String name;

    public Subfamily() {}

    public Subfamily(String name, Family family) {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
    }

    // public getters and setters
}
```

Then I have separated Daos, for insert Family and Subfamily

```
public void insertFamily(Family family) {
    try {
        this.familyDao.create(family);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void insertSubfamily(Subfamily subfamily) {
    try {
        this.subfamilyDao.create(subfamily);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then when I create a Family and Subfamily like this, the foreign field looks always NULL. I Don't know what I'm doing wrong..

```
Family f1 = new Family("FAMILY ONE");
mFamilyDao.insertFamily(f1);
Subfamily s1 = new Subfamily("SUBFAMILY OF FAMILY ONE", f1);
mSubfamilyDao.insertSubfamily(s1);
```

[image: Foreign null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then when I create a Family and Subfamily like this, the foreign field looks always NULL. I Don't know what I'm doing wrong..

```
Family f1 = new Family("FAMILY ONE");
familyDao.insertFamily(f1);
Subfamily s1 = new Subfamily("SUBFAMILY OF FAMILY ONE", f1);
subfamilyDao.insertSubfamily(s1);
```

Ok. This code on the surface looks fine so the following list is more things to try and debugging hints then a solution.

- Are you sure that you don't want `generatedId = true` for both id fields?  Otherwise you are going to need to set the `id` field's value yourself.
- Are you sure that `f1`'d id field is not `null` as well?  Where is that field set?   You should log the value of `f1.getId()` after the `insertFamily(...)` method returns to make sure the value is an integer.
- Do you really want the field to be an `Integer`?  Can the `id` ever be `null`?  I usually use `int` or `long` for my id fields.
- And what is the `insertFamily(...)` doing?  Why aren't you just calling `dao.create(...)`?

Hope something here helps.  Oh and lastly, just say *no* to Hungarian notation if you can.  Use coloration on your IDE to replace it.  :-)

Comment: Great!! the problem was solved with *generatedId = true*. Also thank you for all the tips and advices you gave me.